# How to get the current offset use IDC or IDAPython?

Tags: ida, idapython, idc

When writing an IDA script, how to use IDC or IDAPython to get the file offset for a memory address?

Answer (score 2):

```
offset = idaapi.get_fileregion_offset(ea)
ea = idaapi.get_fileregion_ea(offset)
```

ref:[How to extract the input file offset of a byte in idapython?](https://reverseengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/2835/how-to-extract-the-input-file-offset-of-a-byte-in-idapython)